# Entity Framework Core not detecting changes in model when adding migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working on a .NET Core project using Entity Framework Core for database operations. I have two entities, `Course` and `Subcategory`, with a one-to-many relationship between them. I've added a navigation property to the `Subcategory` entity to represent the collection of `Cours`e entities related to each `Subcategory`.

Here's my `Subcategory` entity:

```
public class Subcategory : BaseEntity
{
    // ... other properties ...

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how I've configured the relationship in my `AppDbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Subcategory)
        .WithMany(s => s.Courses)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.SubcategoryId);
}
```

After making these changes, I added a new migration using the `dotnet ef migrations add` command. However, the generated migration did not include the changes I made to the `Subcategory` and `Course` entities.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, updating the database to make sure it's in sync with the model, and adding the migration again, but the changes are still not included in the new migration.

Does anyone know why Entity Framework is not detecting the changes in my model and how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Check `ModelSnapshot` file. If it already has information about relationship - nothing will be generated, Also compare snapshot with previous `.Designer.cs` migration file. EF Core do not look at database for generating migrations. It uses `ModelSnapshot` file and compares with current model. Difference is recorded in new migration file and new snapshot file is generated.

Comment: If you just added collection navigation property, it does not change anything in the database model, since the FK (and the relationship) already exists.